# Jquery dynamic table validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic table as shown .

[image: Image of the table]

How can restrict the rows have same values in both the columns using jquery or javascript

thanks in advance

Comment: Currently I am using this javascript function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Haim pointed out in the comments that I might have misinterpreted what you were after. So I'll present two options.

**If you want to prevent the same values being selected:**

```
$('table').delegate('select', 'change', function () {
    var other = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').not(this);
    if (other.val() == $(this).val()) {
        // Bad! Now what do you want to do?

        // Select nothing?
        this.selectedIndex = -1;
        // Make the row red?
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
        // Be reallllly annoying?
        alert('You have made a bad choice!');
    }
});
```

**If you want to keep the two columns the same:**

```
$('table').delegate('select', 'change', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('select').not(this).val($(this).val());
});
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yGSNN/

Comment: i think he want to prevent this situation , not to have duplicate values, in your example you make this 2 select box same

Comment: @Haim, oh, that sounds very logical now that you mention it. Did not get that sense at all from the question though.

Comment: Yes I Want to restrict duplicates

Comment: @Tech, see the first part of my answer then ;)

Comment: Box9,   Thanks for the code. This code restrict in the next consecutive cell, what about to compare the entire table rows for any duplicates ?

Comment: @Tech, then instead of `.closest('tr')` use `.closest('table')`, and instead of a simple `if (other.val() == ...)` you have to do: `var current = this; other.each(function () { if ($(this).val() == $(current).val()) { ... }});`